# Who has taken "my" Managed package namespace? Can we find out?

Tags: managed-package, isv, namespace

I wanted to use my company name as a **Namespace Prefix** of a new **Managed Package** App...and it was already taken :-(.

[image]

Is there a way to find out who or which existing app uses it? Technically or by asking Salesforce? Did you ever do it?

There might even be a small chance that we ourselves have taken it and the org still lingers around somewhere. How can we find out?

Comment: Probably fair to say you can't find out on your own for privacy reasons. However perhaps either a Partner Case or a conversation with one of your Partner contacts at Salesforce could help you get in touch with whoever registered it.

Comment: Changing a namespace is a horrible, horrible process. Avoid at all costs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is the possibility of installing the package using Metadata API. Then inspect the company details, package version description or documentation (etc) for meaningful contact information.

For example using JavaScript in browser console:

```
var versionNumber = '1.0';
var activateRSS = 'false';
var nsPrefix = 'MyCompanyName';
var binding = new XMLHttpRequest();

binding.open('POST', 'https://' + window.location.host + '/services/Soap/m/46.0');
binding.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
binding.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
binding.onreadystatechange = function(e) {if (this.readyState == 4) console.log(e.target)};
binding.send(''
    + '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
    + '<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
    + '<Header>'
    + '<SessionHeader xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">'
    + '<sessionId>' + document.cookie.split('sid=')[1].split(';')[0] + '</sessionId>'
    + '</SessionHeader>'
    + '</Header>'
    + '<Body>'
    + '<upsertMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">'
    + '<metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="InstalledPackage">'
    + '<fullName>' + nsPrefix + '</fullName>'
    + '<versionNumber>' + versionNumber + '</versionNumber>'
    + '<activateRSS>' + activateRSS + '</activateRSS>'
    + '</metadata>'
    + '</upsertMetadata>'
    + '</Body>'
    + '</Envelope>'
);
```

If the API responds with a 500 error (for example, deprecated package) then it may be possible to increment the major/minor version numbers to smoke out an installable version *if one exists.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <upsertMetadataResponse>
            <result>
                <created>false</created>
                <errors>
                    <message>InstalledPackage namespace: mycompanyname does not exist!</message>
                    <statusCode>PACKAGING_API_INSTALL_FAILED</statusCode>
                </errors>
                <fullName>MyCompanyName</fullName>
                <success>false</success>
            </result>
        </upsertMetadataResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Amazing idea. But my bad the namespace is taken but no package version has been released. The response says "Package Not Found [04t1i000001EKjV]
The requested package doesn&apos;t yet exist or has been deleted. If this is a recently created package version, please try again in a few minutes or contact the package publisher."

Comment: What actually is FullName? It's namespace plus Package name, right? What if I don't know how this other company that took my ns has named the package?

Comment: @RobertSösemann FullName corresponds to the exact Namespace Prefix. From the response it sounds like only beta versions were uploaded, or no version as you say. Do you have a trademark on the name?

Comment: In case I would, what would you suggest? Sue them ;-)? Do you thinks Salesforce can change Namespace prefixes after they have been created and assigned? Just theoretically...

Comment: @RobertSösemann I would suggest to resolve outside the walls of the courthouse. If you have trademark in good faith and the namespace prefix is squatted in bad faith, tell Salesforce.